# How do I save terminal output into a log file?

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr

I'm running `ycsb`, which sends workload generated by YCSB to mongodb and it has a standard output, which I am storing in the file `outputLoad`.

```
./bin/ycsb load mongodb -s -P workloads/workloada -p mongodb.database=ycsb > outputLoad
```

The `-s` parameter in the command tells it to generate a client report status. The [report status](http://www.filedropper.com/log_7) is printed directly to my terminal. How can I get this status into a log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect standard error (file descriptor `2`) to a file.

```
./bin/ycsb [...options...] > outputLoad 2> mylog.log
```

Comment: If you want stderr and stdout in the same log, 2>&1 > mylog.log

Comment: is that a 4.2,4.3 thing?

Comment: @DTSCode @Jesse `&>` was introduced in 4.0, according to the [release notes](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS). E: oh, that's actually `&>>`. Guess `&>` was always around, then.